# Why all of object's observable property values are functions?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this javascript object:

```
var Email = function (data) {
    this.id = ko.observable();
    this.clientID = ko.observable(data.clientID);
    this.email = ko.observable(data.email);
    this.iscc = ko.observable(data.iscc);
}
```

On button click I'm adding a new `email` to the `emails` array:

```
function addCcEmail () {
     var client = self.selectedItem();
     var email = new Email({ "id": "1", "clientId": "", "email": "", "iscc": "true" });
     console.log(email);
     client.emails.push(email);
}
```

But the result I'm getting on the `console.log` looks like this:

```
Email {id: function, clientId: function, email: function, iscc: function}
```

Didn't I initiale it properly?

Comment: `observable()` are you returning any value from this function??

Comment: What does the JSON tag have to do with this?

Comment: @Durga It's not a function, it's a Knockout declaration.

Comment: @user3378165 it's still a function... do you know what it returns?

Comment: @evolutionxbox A knockout observable `a = ko.observable(1)` returns `1` if invoked without parameters and replaces the stored value when invoked with a parameter: `a(2); a(); // 2`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are doing it correctly. The fact that all properties are displayed as functions is because all their values are `ko.observable`s, which are functions themselves.

If you check `email.id()`, for example, you will get the desired value out of the observable.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I thought something is wrong with my declaration because when I access it in another function: `var mappedEmails = $.map(client.emails(), function (item) {`
            `console.log(item.email());` I'm getting an error on the console: `item.email is not a function`, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user3378165 In your code you're pushing to `client.emails`. I don't see the **invoice** part. If you invoke the `$.map` for the `client.emails`, however, it should work fine.

Comment: @SVSchmidt I wrote it by mistake, just after I edited my comment.

Comment: Could you help?

Comment: `email` is not an observable object, only its properties. Try `var mappedEmails = $.map(client.emails(), function (item) { console.log(item.email.id());`

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, a knockout observable is a function. Therefore, it is logged as `function` (and not the actual value).
The actual value is retrieved by just invoking the function. Assume `a = ko.observable(1)`, then `a(); // 1`.

If you need creating observables from objects, I can recommend the [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), which makes it easy to map every property of an object to an observable (and vice versa).

```js
var Email = function (data) {
    this.id = ko.observable();
    this.clientID = ko.observable(data.clientID);
    this.email = ko.observable(data.email);
    this.iscc = ko.observable(data.iscc);
}

let a = new Email({ id: 1, clientID: 2, email: 'foo@xample.com', iscc: false });

console.log(a);
console.log(ko.mapping.toJS(a));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
```

You could also replace the `Email` function by a single call to `ko.mapping.fromJS(data)`.

I think this makes debugging objects of knockout observables much easier.